# What are the most general and powerful math tricks?

Tags: learning

I quote from the first chapter of Michael Spivak's *Differential Geometry Volume I*:

*The precise definition of $\mathbb{P}^2$ uses the* **same trick that mathematicians always use when they want two things that are not equal to be equal.** *The points of $\mathbb{P}^2$ are defined to be the sets $\{p,-p\}$ for $p \in S^2$...*

That passage burned itself into my brain when I first read it decades ago.  My immediate reaction was, "I want the list!  Where is the list of tricks like that?!"

In my studies I have kept an eye out for tricks that generalize, that carry over into a different area.  I also watch out for very broad categories of trick that have different specific versions in different topics.  I tutor math and physics and have compiled lists of "debugging" steps for when a student is stuck on a problem.  But I have long suspected that there are far more powerful tricks out there that are common knowledge to mathematicians but not to mathematics students.

In an effort to clarify what I am asking, I will write my own best answer, and I hope others can improve, elaborate, or best of all add completely new items to the list.

Comment: I think he's just talking about factoring out an equivalence relation.

Comment: @CalvinLin it was a guess, as I am not really sure what category theory is, and I was hunting for relevant tags and coming up empty.  I'll remove it.

Comment: As a clarification, to what extent do you consider proof techniques like generalize from small cases, contradiction, induction, reducing to a known case, pigeonhole principle, etc "tricks"? I personally would include these (maybe not PP).

Comment: @CalvinLin, I think most of those as logic techniques that everyone solving problems should know. I suppose I think of tricks as things that aren't necessarily taught, and are extremely hard to think of on your own without being taught them.  The pigeonhole principle maybe counts as a trick, but I probably used it before I was ever taught it.

Comment: We teach a lot of specific tricks in school, rarely general ones.

Answer (score 2):

The most general math tricks I know include

1. **Add zero.** An example of this is completing the square.  Faced with $x^2 + 6x + 1$, we can add $0 = 8-8$ to produce $x^2 + 6x + 9 - 8 = (x+3)^2 -8$.
2. **Multiply by one.** The simplest example of this is addition of fractions.  The most common example is probably unit conversions. Other versions include the "conjugate trick" (see below).
3. **Factoring an unknown**. The solution to the cubic equation involves replacing the single variable $x$ with $u-v$, where you now have two variables, and at a later point can use the extra flexibility to declare some messy quantity to equal zero.  A similar technique is variation of parameters in differential equations, where an unknown function is declared to be a different unknown function multiplied by a known one chosen for convenience.
4. **Separation of variables.** Independence in probability is one case, and another is in partial differential equations, writing the solution as a product of solutions depending on variables separately.  Arguably that is a special case of #3.
5. The **"Spivak trick"** quoted in the question.  I have rarely seen this used but it seems powerful and important.
6. **The conjugate trick.** A special case of #2, this is used extremely often, for rationalizing a denominator in fractions, complex arithmetic, L'Hopital's Rule, and more.
7. **Symmetry.**  I don't even know how to characterize this.  While I make significant use of it, there is often yet more symmetry that can be exploited to cut a problem in half, declare an answer zero, and so forth.  It is clearly extremely powerful. But, for example, I once read a 12-page proof that a quintic equation does not have a general solution formula, which seemed to be 11.5 pages of group theory that seemed to have absolutely *nothing* to do with the question, followed by some handwaving and declaring "QED".
8. **Solving a more general problem.** This seems to require the most creativity, and so is hard to really classify as a tool more than a hope.

This is the broadest classification I know.  I have constructed this mental model of techniques slowly over years, and I am curious what other powerful yet comprehensible techniques exist.

Comment: That's a good list, though it seems like you're quite focused on algebraic manipulation. Is that intentional?

Comment: @CalvinLin only in that algebraic tricks are far easier to articulate.  I often use geometric intuition, but it is harder to describe.  Plus the geometric tricks I have seen are often brilliant but I don't see how to generalize them; they often look like unique rabbit-out-of-a-hat solutions, brilliant but nearly impossible to hunt for.